# How do I use a parameter in an #if value in mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm trying to create a mediawiki template:

```
|-
| {{{name}}}{{#if:{{{ref|}}}|<ref>{{{ref}}}</ref>|}}{{#if:{{{ndb|}}}|<ref>https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/{{{ndb}}}</ref>|}} || {{{size|--}}} || {{{carbs|--}}} || {{{sugar|--}}} || {{{fiber|--}}} || {{{fat|--}}} || {{{protein|--}}}
```

Most of it works OK but if I pass a `ref` or a `ndb` parameter, the `#if` doesn't work properly I get

`<ref>{{{ref}}}</ref>`

or

`<ref>https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/{{{ndb}}}</ref>`

I don't get what I would expect:

`<ref>http://the.passed.value/</ref>`

or

`<ref>https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/passed_value</ref>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#if` doesn't seem to be the cause of the issue. The reason is that `<ref>` is not processed in the order you're expecting. You need [`#tag`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words) to generate a parser or extension tag at a later template processing stage:

`Template:Google` source code:

```
<includeonly><!--
-->{{#if: {{{ref|}}}
   | {{#tag: ref |{{{ref}}}}}
   }}<!--
-->{{#if: {{{q|}}}
   | {{#tag: ref |[https://google.com/search?q={{#urlencode:{{{q}}}}} Google: {{{q}}}]}}
   }}<!--
--></includeonly>
```

Page source code:

```
{{Google
| ref = http://google.com/search?q=foo+bar
| q = foo bar
}}

<references/>
```

Page output:

> [1][2]
>
> 1. ↑ http://google.com/search?q=foo+bar
> 2. ↑ [Google: foo bar](http://google.com/search?q=foo+bar)